# Selenium don't executes javascript on webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to **scrape** some data from this url: https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/, but selenium and mechanicalsoup isn't working, because the javascript don't get executed.

my last choice was selenium to grap the data, but now i don't understand, why am i getting the same not executed source code of the website? Javascript is enabled in selenium.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html/')
```

best regards

Comment: have you tried running the JS in normal browser and what was the behavior?

Comment: are you trying to login?

Comment: Sure, i tried it. If i go with a normal browser on this website, i see something. With selenium i don't see anything. @supputuri

Comment: Yes, i am trying to login @0m3r